# SQL Select users with condition verified in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

[image: table services-users]

the first column contains `Services_ID`, the second `Users_ID` and the third indicates if the user is enabled for the service.
I need to identify (one time for user) which users are allowed for both services with `ID` 4 and 5.

I wrote that query with Mysql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT User 
  FROM tablexxx
 WHERE Service IN (4, 5)
   AND User NOT IN (SELECT User
                      FROM tablexxx
                     WHERE Service IN (4, 5)
                       AND Active = FALSE);
```

That query works, but, is there a better technical way to write it?

The right result is:

[image: Result]

Comment: not technical, but a cleaner way (imho): select distinct User from tablexxx where Service = 4 and active = TRUE
intersect
select distinct User from tablexxx where Service = 5 and active = TRUE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select user
from your_table
where service in (4,5)
and active = TRUE
group by user
having count(distinct service) = 2
```

or

```
select user
from your_table
group by user
having sum(active = TRUE and service = 4) > 0
   and sum(active = TRUE and service = 5) > 0
```